# Integrate proxy with playwright codegen from command line

Tags: proxy, playwright, codegen

I'm trying to access page, more specifically in this case Instagram, with paid and working static proxy with the following in the command line

```
playwright codegen --proxy-server="host:port" --username="user" --password="pass" https://instagram.com
```

and got the error `unknown option '--username=user'` I tried to search playwright development documentation but didn't find much information regarding this issue. How do you access an url with proxy with `playwright codegen`?

Comment: Its feature request for playwright codegen https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15137

Answer (score 0):

As of for now it only states the possibility of private proxy requests in the code itself but not via command line `playwright codegen`